# How to solve timetuple error on insert record in dbf

Tags: python, dbf

I need **insert a new record on dbf table**:

```
table.append(('37', '111111', '0', '0', '', '15370', '19/08/14 04:50'))
```

But i'm getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '**timetuple**' on **python**.

Table structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsb4k.jpg

I am using the DBF library

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the tuple should match what the dbf is expecting.  According to your graphic:

```
CODIGO N(3,0)
PRODUTO C(6)
VALOR N(14,4)
DESC_MAX N(5,2)
PREVISAO D
BASE_PERC N(6,2)
CRC N(6,0)
DT_ACTUALIZ ?
```

So you should be passing something like (just using the types):

```
((int, unicode, float, float, date, float, int, ?))
```

That `?` is because I can't see the type of `DT_ATUALIZ` in the graphic.

Comment: DT_ACTUALIZ dont show any information of field type. Just: DT_ACTUALIZ. 

I 'solve' with this:
table.append(('111111', '', 'NOME DO PRODUTO', '', 'un', '', '12', '', ''))

but is there any way for me to insert a new record by completing a few columns (those with index)?

Comment: @user2925795:  Going from the error message and the string you tried to pass in, the type is probably `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

check the order and type of your arguments, the error seems to be saying that one of the arguments is looking for a timetuple attribute from a string which probably means that your last item, the date time, should be a datetime object of somesort rather than a string

Comment: ahm. how can I send datetime for that field (last field), just for a test, an example? It could be the current date, provided it is in that format.

Comment: import datetime module and use the datetime.strptime(str,format) function to convert a string to a date time object

Comment: theres a few resources online on how this works, just searh up datetime documentation or something

Comment: this: strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", gmtime()) solved the problem format, but the problem persist. )):

Comment: interesting...can you call help(table.append) in your python shell and see what tpye each argument should be? it may be a different argument that is wrong. also, are you sure that it's this specific line thats crashing it?